# Display data from phpmyadmin using angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I wish to display data from `mysql database` using `angularJS` but all in vain. Please review my code and suggest me where am I going wrong ?

```
  <?php
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $user = ""; 
    $pass = ""; 
    $database = "abc";
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully'; 
    mysql_select_db($database,$con);  
     //select
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `product`"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 
    $arr = array();
    //now we turn the results into an array and loop through them. 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $name = $row['name']; 
        $description = $row['description']; 
        //echo 'This is: ' . $name . ' ' . $description . "<br/>\n"
        $arr[] = $row;
    } 
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

controllers.js

```
 function ProductListCtrl($scope,$http) {
    $http.get('php/connect.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
    });
    //$scope.orderProp = 'name';

}
```

index.html

```
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="../angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul ng:controller="ProductListCtrl">
        <li ng:repeat="product in products">
            {{product.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run `index.html`, I get infinite list of bullets with no result displayed.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the JSON data that is sent to the page? Perhaps PHP isn't outputting what you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Alexander, if you can get JSON data from your browser console that would help.

I think you wanted to do something like this in your php code to get only name and description
`$arr[] = array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description);` instead of `$arr[] = $row;`

You may be getting back an error from your php code in the form of html and $http is pulling this apart as if it were an array.

hope this helps

--dan

Comment: my mistake :) i forgot to add [] and commas in the generated json

Comment: I use Services_JSON and it has been flawless for me http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198

Comment: Followed your tutorial z22 and happened the same with me, a lot of bullets, what do you mean with forgot to add the [] and commas in the json? where did you put that? :(